# Google account issue?

Tags: bug, android-app

I created an account for Stack Exchange earlier today, via the Android app, and used the Google account option. Then when I went later on from my computer to try to login, I chose the Google account option to login and it's saying I don't have an account. Clearly I do because I'm posting right now (from the Android app)...

Comment: How many google accounts do you have? I have a couple - if I'm in the wrong one it will not recognise me here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's working now, somehow, trying to login today with Google worked immediately... strange!